# Get results from whole hour 3 days ago

Tags: mysql

I have some table with a datetime column, and I want to fetch from it all results like this:

If I execute the query on `2016-01-28 11:12:24`, I want to fetch all results from 3 days ago from that whole hour (`11:00:00`). So I'd get all rows between `2016-01-28 11:00:00` and `2016-01-28 11:59:59`. How do I do this, **so that I can benefit from index** on this datetime column?

I have tried using `WHERE DATE_FORMAT(o.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') = DATE_FORMAT(NOW() INTERVAL -3 DAY, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')` but it is a function, so the query doesn't use an index.

Comment: if you convert `DATE_FORMAT(o.created_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')`to datetime you won't be loosing index probaby (using `Convert`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to do this:

```
WHERE o.created_at >= DATE_FORMAT(date_sub(now(), interval 3 day), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AND o.created_at < DATE_FORMAT(date_add(date_sub(now(), interval 3 day), interval 1 hour), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
```

Alternately, you can also do this but only with precision up to seconds:

```
WHERE o.created_at BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(date_sub(now(), interval 3 day), '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(date_sub(now(), interval 3 day), '%Y-%m-%d %H:59:59')
```

The `BETWEEN AND` clause here still utilizes the Index as we have not used `DATE_FORMAT` function on the column `o.created_at`. It is also much more efficient if the selected data is less than 1/3rd of the total rows.
[Ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html ]

---

Note: Thanks to [@Used_By_Already](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2067753/used-by-already) for pointing out the issue with precision up to microseconds.

Comment: What happens if the data precision is finer then one second? MySQL 5.7 has fractional seconds support up to microseconds (6 digits) precision. My advice is to **never** use *between* for date ranges. Use >= with < instead

Comment: @Used_By_Already: Yes, as you indicated it is better to use >= and < when the precision is finer to the extent of microseconds. However, that would be essential for only version 5.7.

Comment: It really does not matter, the issue is some day the precision will increase and if code is hardcoded to 23:59:59 style solutions you get instant bugs. Way better to always use code that will remain accurate. I do not compromise on this I **never** use *between* for date ranges.

Comment: @Used_By_Already: Thanks for pointing this out. Made the edits required.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of formating a new date with `NOW() Interval - 3....`, take a look at `DateDiff()`. This allows you to set the difference from `NOW()` to other days and set the measure unit.